# What is likely problem with my HDMI display?

Tags: hdmi

I have trouble getting FullHD resolution out of my HDMI monitor. First of all I have to force hotplug to get it to display anything, and then it only shows max resolution 1280x720, instead of FHD, no matter what higher mode I try to set.

What could be the problem? Display? HDMI cable? EDID stuff? Any suggestions how to solve this?

Asking here, because I'm not sure how to proceed with troubleshooting, and I did not find a wiki page or anything that helped (closest was this: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Display)

Comment: What display are you using?

Comment: HP 2311x, about a year old 23" computer monitor without any audio.

Comment: I got a chance to try with another display, and it worked, so I guess it's display problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you using? If you are talking about XBMC distros: Some of the force 720p resolution for performance. But (at least in raspbmc and xbian) you can disable it.

Comment: Old issue. It was with Raspbian, at least. I think it was a combination of configuration in config.txt (forcing some HDMI stuff), and display being in sleep mode when RPi started so things didn't get detected properly... But thanks for the answer, I'll mark it accepted to "close" this old question :)